# Read json number and display it in text

Tags: json, angularjs

In my table i display name and points, but points comes out in numbers like 10,20 , 30 ,40.
I want it to if someone has 10 points, it should be bronze member in the td table {x.ponts} ,20 for silver, 30 for gold and 40 for elite.

You dont need to solve it, its enough with just some help what i did wrong.

```
         <table>
                <tr ng-repeat="x in Id">
                    <td>{{ x.id }}</td>
                    <td>{{ x.name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ x.points }}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>


    <script>
        function customersController($scope, $http) {
        $http.get("mylocalhostlink")
        .success(function (response) { $scope.Number = response });
```

i thought something like this... am i close?

```
                angular.forEach($scope.Id, function (value) {

                    switch (value.status) {
                        case 10:
                            $scope.points = bronze;
                            break;
                        case 20:
                            $scope.points = silver;
                            break;
                        case 30:
                            $scope.points = gold;
                            break;
                        case 40:
                        $scope.points= elite;
                        break;

                        default:
                            console.log(value.status);


                    }



     </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you need to create a `points` filter. [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/XL4Txagw8o8KwjnvWwgp?p=preview)

```
<td>{{ x.points  | points }}</td>
```

Add a points filter.

```
app.filter('points', function() {
    return function(input) {
        var point;
        switch (input) {
            case 10:
                point = 'bronze';
                break;
            case 20:
                point = 'silver';
                break;
            case 30:
                point = 'gold';
                break;
            case 40:
                point = 'elite';
                break;

            default:
                point = 'none';

        }

        return point;
    };
});
```

Comment: doesnt work for me. Do i need to add a ng change or something?

Comment: when i add | points to the table, it doesnt work, it doesnt even display anything in the table

Comment: Controller should not be put under global namespace, filter code should be out of controller.Check the plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/hoIwdgwOWOQq4GGMGpuo?p=preview

Comment: i did like you said, but as soon as i write in my table again, whole ng repeat crashes